# Angular Component Expects 2 Arguments

Tags: wordpress, angular, typescript

I'm attempting to create a Wordpress theme compatible with 4.8.x that will render single posts and list of posts as per [this tutorial]:[1](http://doppiaeast.com/article/angular-2-wordpress-theme-setup/)

When I run the test script, I receive the following errors:

```
ERROR in C:/MyTheme/src/app/posts/post-list/post-list.component.spec.ts 
(9,25): Expected 2 arguments, but got 0.

ERROR in C:/MyTheme/src/app/posts/post-single/post-single.component.spec.ts 
(8,25): Expected 2 arguments, but got 0.
```

The code for both components is very similar and calls into the PostsService which is defined as:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Post } from './post';
import { environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class PostsService {
private _wpBase = environment.wpBase;

constructor(private http: HttpClient)    { }

getPosts():Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get<Post[]>(this._wpBase + 'posts');
  }

getPost(slug: string): Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.http.get<Post[]>(this._wpBase + 'posts?slug=${slug}');
  }
}
```

My post-list-component includes the following:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Post } from '../post';
import { PostsService} from '../posts.service';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
selector: 'app-post-list',
templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.css'],
providers: [PostsService]
})
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {
posts: Post[];

constructor( private  postsService: PostsService, private router: Router ){}
ngOnInit() {
    this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe(
        (posts: Post[]) => this.posts = posts,
        (err: HttpErrorResponse) => err.error instanceof Error ?
    console.log('An error has occurred:', 
    err.error.message):console.log('Backend returned code $(err.status), 
    body was: ${err.error}'));
}

selectPost(slug) {
    this.router.navigate([slug]);
}
}
```

The error is thrown in the following post.list.component.spec.ts:

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */

import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { PostListComponent } from './post-list.component';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

describe('Component: PostList', () => {
    it('should create an instance', () => {
    let component = new PostListComponent();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
});
```

I am not sure how to resolve the errors.  It seems to me that PostLisComponent() needs to be passed 2 arguments as per the error, but it's not clear what arguments should be passed.  Can anyone assist me in better understanding how to resolve the errors?

Comment: *"it's not clear what arguments should be passed"* - well the `constructor` definition gives you a pretty good idea, no? But you shouldn't be newing up components yourself, *that's the whole point of Angular's DI* and the associated `TestBed`. Read https://angular.io/guide/testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because the constructor use TestBed

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { PostListComponent } from './post-list.component';

describe('PostListComponent ', () => {
    let component: PostListComponent ;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<PostListComponent >;

beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ PostListComponent ]
})
.compileComponents();}));
beforeEach(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PostListComponent );
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  fixture.detectChanges();
});
it('should create an instance', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Angular's Testing Guide](https://angular.io/guide/testing) in regards to the `TestBed`, and why it would fit such a scenario:

> `TestBed` is the first and most important of the Angular testing
>   utilities ... In effect, you detach the tested component from its own
>   application module and re-attach it to a **dynamically-constructed**
>   Angular test module tailored specifically for this battery of tests.

Right now, you're statically constructing instead of dynamically constructing using the `TestBed`, which is causing the error since the constructor of the `PostListComponent` contains two parameters which would be required to be filled in case of static constructing.